# What happend to the Dancing Fool and Coffin Jobe at the end of the `The spy who haunted me`?

Tags: secret-history

At the end of `The spy who haunted me` from the `Secret Histories` series, when `Eddie` and `Walker` raided `Place Gloria`, they left the Dancing Fool and Coffin Jobe there and after killing Alexander King they destroyed Place Gloria with both the Dancing Fool and Coffin Jobe still hanging there!
I wonder if that's a loose end! Did Green forget about it?!

Comment: Thanks for the tag @Pixel. It would be super if you could add another tag to this question and that would be `secret-histories`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear to be so. Coffin Jobe does turn up in the first section of "For Heaven's Eyes Only" (when Harry is in Limbo), so he did make it out somehow.

Comment: Yes, just read it today,